# Cons of using Ajax for Autocomplete search operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, reactjs, e-commerce

I am working on E-commerce application & I want to implement a google like search functionality with autocomplete and spelling correction.

1. What are the cons if I implement this using Ajax, I mean in terms of performance and the load on the server since its E-commerce website.
2. Are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you should try and use observables before you hit the ajax. Observables from the rxjs library will let you plan how to use your autocomplete so that you aren't hitting the server unnecessarily. One example is a debounce Time so that you don't trigger a new search every time a user types, but instead wait a couple of seconds for the user to finish typing. This will also allow you to avoid hitting the server when a user has a typo and uses backspace.